# Facebook Requests dialog - is there a way to disable frictionless requests?

Tags: facebook, social-networking, facebook-requests

I am developing a Facebook app.

In that app, i have to send apprequests to multiple users.
I am using the [Requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to send requests.

In the dialog, the friends list appears with a check box saying "Don't ask again before sending requests to these friends from this app".

I do not want that check box. How can i remove that option? Where can i change that setting either in JS SDK or Developer App settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the documentation is incorrect, you need to pass `frictionlessRequests: true` in your call to `FB.init()` order to trigger frictionless requests.

If you are doing this and don't want frictionless requests, don't supply that option in the call to `FB.init()`.

If you're not, and the checkbox is still appearing automatically, you should use the `Report Documentation Bug` link on the documentation to ask Facebook to update the docs